# Sequential column sum

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
init = 0  
final = 8000  
out = 3000  
vals = c(rexp(10000, 0.0002))
```

I want to add columns (30) with a linear combination of variables list above, like this:

```
col1 = init + vals(1,) - out  
col2 = col1 + vals(1,) - out  
...  
col30 = col29 + vals(1,) - out
```

And do it for all 10.000 rows:

```
col1 = init + vals(n,) - out  
col2 = col1 + vals(n,) - out  
...  
col30 = col29 + vals(n,) - out
```

How can I do this with a loop?

Still, each calculated value can't be greater than "final" and not less than "init", and should be rounded to these values (8000 and 0).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this *loop* over the 30 columns with a simple `for-loop`. Over the 10.000 rows you don't need to loop as they are computed automatically by using the vector. `pmin`and `pmax` is used for your condition that each calculated value can't be greater than "final" and not less than "init". `cbind` joins the columns together.

```
init = 0  
final = 8000  
out = 3000  
vals = c(rexp(10000, 0.0002))

tt  <- pmin(final, pmax(init, init + vals - out))
vals  <- cbind(vals, tt)
for(i in 2:30) {
  tt  <- pmin(final, pmax(init, tt + vals[,1] - out))
  vals  <- cbind(vals, tt)
}
dimnames(vals)[[2]][2:31]  <- paste0("col", 1:30)
```

Hope this is close to what you wanted.